# JPA - Retrieving information from connected tables

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

So lets say i have these two classes:

```
@Entity
public class Reservation extends Observable implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private ReservationState state;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private CafeteriaUser user;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="idMeal",referencedColumnName= "idMeal")
private Meal meal;
```

And

```
@Entity
public class Meal implements Serializable {

private Price price;
private MealType mealType;
private Dish m_dish;

@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar date;

@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Menu menu;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long idMeal;

public Meal() {
}
```

Now, I'm having trouble 'connecting' these two tables. What would be the equivalent of getting the reservations by a given date (select * from Reservation r,Meal m where r.idMeal = m.IDMEAL and m."DATE" = '2016-01-01') in JPQL?

It seems using r.idMeal = m.idMeal gives me "The collection-valued path 'r.idMeal' cannot be resolved to a valid association field." error

Comment: r.idMeal is NOT a collection valued path (based on what you post). r.idMeal is however a Meal object, and m.idMeal is a Long ... so they are not comparable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic JPQL would be like this

```
SELECT r FROM Reservation r JOIN r.meal m WHERE m.date = :date
```

and pass in the date as a parameter. This should be evident from the vast majority of JPQL tutorials out there